# How to download the GFS 2m Temperature data?

Tags: weather-forecasting, gfs

I am attempting to download the 2m temperature forecast from the GFS forecasts archived by AWS's open dataset archive. I am having some issues figuring out the feature name to search for in the file names in order to get the correct data. I am filtering for grib2 files and am getting file names such as "gfs.20201030/18/gfs.t18z.gtg.0p25.f003.grib2" but none of them contain any containing a temperature feature name? What feature name should I be looking for, or am I just doing this all wrong? I appreciate any help on this newbie issue, as I have spent a couple of days trying to figure it out coming from the GEFS Reforecasts and am still stumped.

Comment: What software are you using to look at the data?

Comment: Perhaps an idea of which location you're using (if there are multiple?)  Because https://docs.opendata.aws/noaa-gfs-pds/readme.html suggests the name format should be different, if I'm looking in the right spot.  Generally if I remember right GFS temperature was just 2mT in NOAA's GFS files (but it's been a while, maybe it's changed)